# Is it true that $\int_a^{a+T}f(x)\,dx \,=\, \int_0^Tf(x)\,dx $ for function $f$ with period $T$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

I was wondering if the following property holds true for the definite integrals of periodic functions:

Consider a function $f(x)$ with period $T$, ie;

$$f (x + T) = f (x) $$

If $a$ is a real number in the domain of the function, then

$$\int_a^{a+T}f(x)\,dx \,=\, \int_0^Tf(x)\,dx $$

Is this true? It seems intuitive, especially for functions like $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ or $\{x\}$, but I was unable to prove it.

Any kind of hint/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference of the two sides is
$$\int_a^{a+T}f(x)\,dx-\int_0^T f(x)\,dx
=\int_T^{a+T}f(x)\,dx-\int_0^af(x)\,dx$$
which vanishes by periodicity.

Comment: Do you assume that $0<a<T$ here?

Comment: I don't since I use the usual conventions for integrals with limits in the "wrong" order. @HenningMakholm

Comment: Let $F$ be an antiderivative and replace $\int_u^v$ by $F(v)-F(u)$ throughout.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. But you then need a separate appeal to periodicity to argue that the integral between $T$ and $a$ exists and is finite.

Comment: This proof makes it look almost too simple, thanks!

Comment: Nice proof. Just to fill in the gap for some readers to see that the RHS is 0, you can do a $u$-substitution $u=x-T$ so that $\int_T^{a+T}f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(u+T)du=\int_0^a f(u)du$.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is true (provided of course that the integrals exist).

Write $a=mT+b$ with $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $0\le b<T$.
Then 
$$\begin{align} \int_a^{a+T}f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\int_a^{(m+1)T}f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{(m+1)T}^{a+T}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_a^{(m+1)T}f(x-mT)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{(m+1)T}^{a+T}f(x-(m+1)T)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_b^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{0}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_b^{T}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^Tf(x)\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought of writing a = mT + b, although it seems painfully obvious now.