# Proving $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(2n) |^2=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\bigg(f(x)^2+f(x)f\big(x+\frac{1}{2}\big)\bigg)$ for $f \in PC$, $1$-periodic

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

I've been thinking about this problem for a while now with no success:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ in $PC$ (piecewise continuous) and $1$-periodic. Using the
> function: $$g(x)=f(x)+f\big(x+\frac{1}{2}\big)$$ prove:
>
> $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \big|\hat{f}(2n)
> \big|^2=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\bigg(f(x)^2+f(x)f\big(x+\frac{1}{2}\big)\bigg)
>  $$
>
> where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient.

I've been messing around with Parseval's equality, since the function is in $L^2$, and exploring both the LHS and the RHS, as well as by integrating $g$ to see if there's any term that looks like it might yield the equality, but nothing came of this. I cannot see any other way of approaching this without using Parseval - so I'm convinced it has to be related, but I just can't see the way (I might be mistaken on this, of course).

My closest attempt yielded (unless I have a mistake) that the RHS equals $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{g}(m)|^2$, but I still couldn't find a way for it to equal the LHS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what is $PC$?

Comment: @Feng Of course - sorry. I'll fix the question. It stands for piecewise continuous.

Comment: Hint: What is the Fourier expansion of $f(x+1/2)$?

Comment: The integral can be interpreted as the inner product of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $L^2(0,1).$ Use the Parseval identity.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes - I also got that result, but how would you continue from there? I got stuck at that point (I recall using inner product properties to get $||f||$ as one of the terms and then didn't see the path from there).

Comment: $\int f(x)g(x)\,dx =\sum \hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct. It suffices to notice that
$$\hat g(m)=\begin{cases} 2\hat f(m), & m \text{ is even,}\\ 0, & m \text{ is odd}.\end{cases}$$
Indeed, using the definition of Fourier coefficients,
\begin{align*}
\hat g(m)&=\hat f(m)+\int_0^1 f(x+1/2) e^{-2\pi imx}\,dx\\
&=\hat f(m)+e^{\pi im}\int_0^1 f(x+1/2) e^{-2\pi im(x+1/2)}\,dx\\
&=\hat f(m)+(-1)^m\hat f(m),\qquad m\in\mathbb Z.
\end{align*}
Here we use a result for periodic fucntions: if $h(x)=h(x+T)$ and $h$ is integrable on $[0,T]$, then
$$\int_0^Th(x)\,dx=\int_a^{a+T}h(x)\,dx,\qquad a\in\mathbb R.$$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748530/is-it-true-that-int-aatfx-dx-int-0tfx-dx-for-function-f?noredirect=1) for a proof of the above result.